# Can I run a react native-cli app with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react-native app that was created using Reacti-native CLI. Throughout that process, I used android studio to run the app. I want use parts of this app in another app that I created using Expo-cli.

Would it be possible to use run this same app but using expo CLI instead? Or should I just copy the code (that I want to re-use) into my new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to expo doc `All apps created with create-react-native-app, are compatible with Expo CLI without changes.`

Please follow this guide https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#upgrading-from-1140-to-201

Comment: Thank you very much. Don't know how I missed this.